# kafka listener can not find consumerfactory

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

The issue is that when registering consumer factory bean with code,
and consume with annotation `kafkaListener`, will throw exception:

> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'whoami13' is expected to be of type 'org.springframework.kafka.config.KafkaListenerContainerFactory' but was actually of type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.GenericBeanDefinition'

this is weird for me.

Code sample like below:

```
    GenericBeanDefinition beanDefinition = (GenericBeanDefinition) b2.getBeanDefinition();
    beanDefinition.setBeanClass(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory.class);
    beanDefinition.setAutowireMode(AbstractBeanDefinition.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE);
    configurableBeanFactory.registerSingleton("whoami13", beanDefinition);
```

Comment: `registerSingleton` is used to register a bean instance, not a bean definition. You need to provide more context about what you are trying to do and why you need to register the factory dynamically; there may be a better way.

Comment: tks for ur comment,I need to register several customize beandefination during spring startup.
if i wanna register beandefination, which api is a better option?
tks

Comment: as u suppose, change registerSingleton to         registry.registerBeanDefinition("whoami13", beanDefinition);
it is work;
tks for ur help